# Itemize list like table of contents

Tags: itemize

I would like to create a list of items that looks like a table of contents:

```
Item 1 ......................... Item 1 price
Item 2 ......................... Item 2 price
Item 3 ......................... Item 3 price
```

etc.

How do I reproduce the dotted line inside an `itemize` environment? Or is there a better tool for this task (like a table, maybe)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you can, please provide a minimal (non-)working example showing what you have tried so far. This will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to reproduce these dotted lines is the `\dotfill` command. You can also use it in a `itemize` environment. The shortest solution is the following

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1 \dotfill Description 1
  \item Item 2\dotfill Description 2
  \item A Longer Item 3 \dotfill A Longer Description 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This gives you the following:
[image]

Comment: ok, I was looking for the dotfill command, thanks!

Comment: @JennyC If you are producing lists you should consider the use of the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 4):

A solution without having to write `\dotfill` for each item. I define a new `pricelist` environment, of `description` type, and patch the `\item` command `inside` this environment, with the help of the `etoolbox`  and `letltxmacro` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\usepackage{etoolbox, letltxmacro}

\AtBeginEnvironment{pricelist}{%
\LetLtxMacro{\priceitem} {\item}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand\item[1][]{\olditem[{#1}] \dotfill \enspace }}%

\newenvironment{pricelist}{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pricelist}
    \item[First item] Item 1 price
    \item[Second item] Item 2 price
    \item[Third item] Item 3 price
\end{pricelist}

\end{document}
```

[image]